# When saving image it saves it as black transparent instead of the real image

Tags: java, image, transparency

When saving the image in it turns into a black square instead of the chosen image, I want to be able to save images from my computer and save it in folder in the project so when zipped and sent they can view the image I uploaded.

I have tried `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` but I don't know if that is the problem.

```
private void imageToArray(){
    int width = originalBI.getWidth();
    int height = originalBI.getHeight();

    newBI = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    pixels = new int[width][height];

    for(int i = 0; i<width;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<height;j++){
            pixels[i][j]=originalBI.getRGB(i,j);
        }
    }
}

private void saveImage(){
    int returnValue = saveFileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);

    if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try{
            ImageIO.write(newBI, "png",saveFileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            lblMessage.setText("Image File Succesfully saved");

        }catch(IOException ex){
            lblMessage.setText("Failed to save image file");
        }
    }
    else{
        lblMessage.setText("No file Choosen");
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you actually doing with your "pixels" 2D array after declaring/loading it ?

Comment: You literally call a function called `getRGB`. That does not give the impression it handles the alpha channel too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not need to work pixel by pixel, which would be slow.

```
private void imageToArray(){
    int width = originalBI.getWidth();
    int height = originalBI.getHeight();

    newBI = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = newBI.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalBI, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();

}
```

One can create a Graphics to draw with.

There are various methods, like using a background color should part of the image be transparent.